# Should I use a comma before "for example"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

In the sentence

> a lot of our modern conveniences are contributing to our unhealthy lifestyle, for example we often use a car instead of walk to the local shops.

Is it correct to use a comma before *for example*?

It sounds more natural to to me to use a period and start a new sencence with *for example*, but isn't there a rule that says that it is gramatically wrong to start a new sentence with conjunction? Or maybe *for example* is not a conjunction? What about adding a comma after *for example*

Note that I am taking the IELTS exam, so I would like to know the "correct" way.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need a punctuation mark there, either a comma or a full stop. For the latter, see https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction

Comment: A comma after "for example" would also be appropriate.